# Pseudo code: Random Permutation

Tags: java, pseudocode

I have a pseudo code that I have translated into java code but anytime I run the code, I get an empty arraylist as a result but it is supposed to give me a random list of integers.
Here is the pseudo code:

```
Algorithm 1. RandPerm(N)
Input: Number of cities N
1) Let P = list of length N, (|P|=N) where pi=i
2) Let T = an empty list
3) While |P| > 0
4)    Let i = UI(1,|P|)
5)    Add pi to the end of T
6)    Delete the ith element (pi) from P
7) End While
Output: Random tour T
```

Here is the java code:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> RandPerm(int n)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> P = new ArrayList<>(n);
        ArrayList<Integer> T = new ArrayList<>();
        int i;

        while(P.size() > 0)
        {
            i = CS2004.UI(1, P.size());// generate random numbers between 1 and the size of P
            T.add(P.get(i));
            P.remove(P.get(i));
        }   
        return T;
    }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: From your code, `P` is always empty, you never add anything to it. Also note that the `n` you are passing is for the initial capacity, but the list's size is `0`.

Comment: the while-loop never executes becuase P starts out empty.  By giving it "n" you are just allocating that much initial space in its backing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>(n);
```

... creates an **empty list** with an **initial capacity** of `n`.

All this does is tell the `ArrayList` what size array to initialise as backing store - most of the time you achieve nothing useful by specifying this.

So your `while(p.size() > 0)` runs zero times, because `p.size()` is zero at the start.

In the pseudocode "where pi=i" suggests to me that you want to initialise the list like this:

```
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
     p.add(i)
  }
```

(I have lowercased your variable name - in Java the convention is for variables to startWithALowerCaseLetter -- only class names StartWithUpperCase. It's also the Java convention to give variables descriptive names, so `cityIdentifiers` perhaps)

Comment: if I try to populate P using a for loop this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at Lab15.Lab15.RandPerm(Lab15.java:54)
 at Lab15.Lab15.main(Lab15.java:28)

Comment: The message tells you exactly what the error is `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9` - you're trying to `get` index 9. The size of the list is 9, so you can only `get` indexes from 0 to 8. You either need to ensure that `CS2004.UI()` returns an index that's in-range, or manipulate what it returns so that it's in-range.

Comment: I am able to get it working by subtracting 1 from the random numbers `i = CS2004.UI(1, P.size())-1;` is now displaying the random numbers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to know that, even if you fix the problem that P is always empty, there are 2 more issues with your implementation.

One is that `P.remove(P.get(i))` does not necessarily remove the ith item if the list has equal value items. It scans from the beginning and removes the first occurrence of the item. See [ArrayList.remove(Object obj)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-). You should use `P.remove(i)` instead for the correct results.

Then the performance is O(n^2). The reason is that ArrayList remove an item by shifting all the subsequent items one slot to the left, which is an O(n) operation. To get a much better performance, you can implement your own "remove" operation by swapping the item to the end. When you generate the next random index, generate it within the range `[0, beginning index of the removed items at the end)`. Swapping is O(1) and the overall performance is O(n). This is called Knuth Shuffle by the way.